# MODX Header Content-Type

Tags: apache, modx, header, яндекс-поиск, content-type

В MODX подготовлен документ к выдаче тип стоит xml
в header отдается:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

для правильно обработки Яндексом нужно что бы xml документ отдавался с типом:

```
Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8
```

Как правильно поступить? Создать новый тип документа или профиксить текущий xml
и если профиксить то в каком месте это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0):

нужно войти в панели управления в Содержимое->Типы содержимого там создать тип RSS (если у кого то как у меня нет) указать в этом типе в поле MIME-type "application/rss+xml". И потом в документе выбрать, что документ этого типа.